# Why override operators aren't working with pointer?

Tags: c++, overriding

I need to write a class Matrix with override operators + - * = and I've got some code that is works, but there is error.

```
//Matrix.h

template <class T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(int rows, int columns);
    Matrix(const Matrix<T> &m);
    Matrix<T>& operator=(Matrix<T>& m);
    Matrix<T> operator+(Matrix<T>& m) const;
    Matrix<T>* operator*(Matrix<T>* m);
};

template <class T> Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator*(Matrix<T>& m) {  
    Matrix<T>* newMatrix = new Matrix<T>(rowCount, m.colCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.colCount; ++j)
        {
            newMatrix->data[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < colCount; ++k)
                newMatrix->data[i][j] += data[i][k] * m.data[k][j];
        }
    }
    return *newMatrix;
}
```

And override operators work fine in this code

```
Matrix<int> matrix(2, 2);
matrix = matrix + matrix;
//and other operators work fine here
```

But here it gives an error during compilation

```
Matrix<int>* matrix = new Matrix<int>(2, 2);
matrix = matrix + matrix;
matrix = matrix * matrix;
//etc
```

error

```
error C2804: binary "operator +" has too many parameters
```

Comment: `*matrix = *matrix + *matrix;` and so on?

Comment: You can't call overloaded operators on a pointer type itself, only on (dereferenced) object instances, so either on object (*matrix) or by following the pointer itself matrix->operator + (other);

Comment: `Matrix<T>* operator*(Matrix<T>* m);` -- That would confuse someone trying to use your `Matrix` class.  Why not return a `Matrix<T>`, and why not simply pass a const reference to a `Matrix`?  Why is the interface to `operator *` different than `operator +`?  A user would expect the operations on the Matrix to have the same interface, not different interfaces, different return types, different argument types, etc.

Comment: And why do you `new` a matrix that you then return by reference? No one will `delete` it, ever.

Comment: `template <class T> Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator*(Matrix<T>& m)` -- This should return a `Matrix` object, not a reference.  Honestly, there is no reason to use *any* pointers in the code.

Comment: Once you get the code working get it reviewed at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type information is crutal in C++.

This:

```
Matrix<int> matrix(2, 2);
matrix = matrix + matrix;
```

Here the type of `matrix` is `Matrix`. You have defined what the `operator +`  for the type `Matrix` so this works fine.

---

This second one is different:

```
Matrix<int>* matrix = new Matrix<int>(2, 2);
matrix = matrix + matrix;
```

Here the type of `matrix` is `Matrix*`. Notice the star on the end of Matrix (this makes it a `Matrix Pointer`). This is a different type than above. You have not defined what `operator +` does for `Matrix*` so the compiler looks at its default operations and finds something close but not exact enough and generates an appropriate error message that tries to help.

To use the `operator +` you defined above you need to make sure the types of the values are `Matrix` and **NOT** `Matrix*`. You can covert a `Matrix*` into a `Matrix` by dereferencing the pointer via `operator *`.

```
Matrix<int>* matrix = new Matrix<int>(2, 2);
(*matrix) = (*matrix) + (*matrix);
```

Here: `(*matrix)` dereferences the `Matrix*` object and you get a `Matrix`. This can now correctly be applied to the `operator +` you defined above.

---

But saying all that.
That explains whay your problem is, but I don't think you actually want (or need) to use `new` in this context.

Dynamically allocating memory like this is probably not the correct way to implement this. It is usually better to use automatic variables (as this makes memory management easier).

```
template <class T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator*(Matrix<T>& m)
// I also removed the & from the return value
// So that the value is copied out of the function.
// because with dynamic allocation the result will disappear
// after the function exits.
// Note: Though the matrix may be officially copied out
//       the compiler is likely to optimize away this copy.
//       and when you upgrade your class with move semantics
//       then it will definitely be moved.
{  
    Matrix<T> newMatrix(rowCount, m.colCount);
    // Remove the Pointer from the above line.
    // And fix the -> into . in the code below.


    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.colCount; ++j)
        {
            newMatrix.data[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < colCount; ++k)
                newMatrix.data[i][j] += data[i][k] * m.data[k][j];
        }
    }
    return newMatrix;
    // Now you can remove the * from the return value.
    // The code works exactly the same.
    // But you have not leaked the memory you allocated with `new`
}
```